# Google +1 button reports an error when clicked

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I have my personal domain, adamtibi.net which is using the free version of Google Apps for email. I have implemented the g +1 button, this is an example page: http://www.adamtibi.net/06-2013/five-essential-front-end-tools-that-should-be-used-with-modern-mvc-projects

Whenever I click the button, I get my g +1 displaying a dialog then suddenly I get an error (the button shows the red warning triangle).

This problem occurs on Win8, IE10, latest FF and latest Chrome. Also, it occurs when I am using a Google account that is on my domain and when I use another Google account not on the domain, so it occurs all the time on all browsers and all accounts. I have also troubleshoot the JS and double checked it, but all the doesn't seem to take the error away.

What is left is this point "Apps user: If your administrator hasn't enabled Google+ for your domain, you won't be able to sign up for a Google+ account to use the +1 button."

I am not sure that this is the case, as if it is, then I will have to upgrade to a premium account which doesn't which would be an over-killing for what I need.

> Is not being a premium Google Apps use the problem? And if I dropped
>   Google Apps for my website would that solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be your +1 code:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-href="$link"></div>
```

Compare this to your Facebook link:

```
<div class="fb-like" 
  data-href="http://www.adamtibi.net/06-2013/five-essential-front-end-tools-that-should-be-used-with-modern-mvc-projects" (...)>
</div>
```

It looks like the issue is the $link variable isn't getting parsed / exported for your Google+ button. Try and update the variable $link to render the same URL as your other social buttons.

Comment: Silly me, you are right, I am more used to Razor code such as having @link on its own would work.